# HTML5 video won't auto play in a React App when the page loads for the first time

Tags: reactjs, mobile, html5-video

I've been trying to use HTML5 video in my React App with autoplay and looping enabled. But it never seems to work when the page loads up the 1st time. But when I visit other pages and come back to the home page (where the video is), the video starts playing. I'm using the following code:

```
 <Section gridStart="1366px" bgColor="gradient" type="flex">
      <Block flexBasis="70">
        <video width="100%" autoPlay loop>
          <source src="/videos/ai-vid.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
      </Block>
      <Block flexBasis="30">
        <Paragraph>
          <Fade bottom cascade>
            <H2 light>Accessibility</H2>
            <H4 light>
              Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
              Molestias dolores quia sit harum accusamus quaerat
              repudiandae.
            </H4>
          </Fade>
        </Paragraph>
      </Block>
    </Section>
```

Plz, let me know what I'm doing wrong here. Any suggestion to improve this code so that it runs on all browsers and mobile devices will be he highly appreciated. Btw, I did try to load the video the following way:

```
import video from 'static/video/ai-vid.mp4'
...
<source src={video} type="video/mp4" />
```

And had no luck, same result. Thanx.

Comment: Just set muted true for autoplay <video width="100%" autoPlay loop muted={true}>, because of browser policy.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out video autoplay was prevented by browser policy. I just had to use 'muted' property to the video and now it's playing fine on Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

## This worked for me

- Make sure you use `autoPlay` instead of `autoplay` for react.
- Also add `muted`

If you want to use the `autoplay` with small letters, you should assign the value `autoplay="true"`

Comment: I cannot use with muted ?.I wanted to use the video with audio as well

Comment: @MuhammadMuneebWaqas That is intentionally disallowed with modern browsers.